# Only redirect if not mobile?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to create a redirect if the user agent is not mobile. Unfortunately I can't get it done.

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}   !"android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/home" [R=302,L]
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done

```
# REDIRECT DESKTOP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|opera\smobile|palmos|webos) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/home" [R=302,L]

# REDIRECT MOBILE
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\/home$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/mobile" [R=302,L]
```